# Markdown headings not appearing in outline box in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

While editing a markdown document in VS Code, the outline box does not show me the outline of the markdown document; it's completely blank/empty. I've disabled all extensions with no change in behavior (and I only had one markdown-related extension anyway, markdownlint). I don't know that this has ever worked, but it certainly has not for the last several months.

- OS: Mac OS 12.3
- VS Code: 1.65.2

[image]

Comment: Please show a snippet of `README.md`. I do get headings in the outline list on my machine.

Comment: @Chris - I've replaced the screenshot with one of the whole editor window (shrunk down), also showing the mode. Thanks!

Comment: Do you happen to have "Outline: Show Strings" disabled in your preferences? Markdown headings show up as text nodes for me, and if I disable that feature the headings disappear from the outline.

Comment: That's it -- thank you! Sadly, I can't toggle that on just for one language ("This setting does not support per-language configuration"). If you put this in as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I actually think it does work just for Markdown if that's what you want. I've added an answer and included that detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box, Markdown headings should show up in the outline view as text nodes:

[image: VSCode outline pane showing three headings]

If the outline view is configured not to show strings, Markdown headers won't appear.

Take a look at the **Outline: Show Strings** setting in your preferences and make sure it's enabled.

This setting is called `outline.showStrings`. If you wish to enable it only for Markdown files, you should be able to disable the feature globally and then add something like this to your `settings.json`:

```json
"[markdown]": {
  "outline.showStrings": true
},
```

It's probably easiest to start by running **Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings...** in the command palette and then selecting Markdown.

Comment: I see them in .md tab, but not in the Preview of the .md

Comment: @SinisaRudan, it [looks like](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131397) that [isn't supported yet](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97095).